# When a process is being attached to, how can I capture the corresponding message

Tags: c++, windows, events, message

I'm working with an application (a service, in fact), and I'd like to add a logging handler for different cases: need for logging to an external file, need for logging to another service, ..., but here I'm interested in the case where the application is subject of "Attach to process" debugging.

The way of working is the following: I've written a logging manager, which contains several logging handlers, and when the application asks to log something, the logging manager goes through all logging handlers and asks them to perform the logging they're responsible for.

E.g.:
When an external file exists, the application (at start-up) reads the file and adds the corresponding logging handler to the logging manager.
The "TEST_CLASS" macro will be replaced with another macro, which might decide to add another logging handler to the logging manager.

Now I have following issue: I would like to know at which moment the application is subject of an "Attach to process": when that happens I'll add the corresponding logging handler to the logging manager (this logging handler is based on `OutputDebugString()`).

In case you wonder "But why making things so complicated? Just put `OutputDebugString()` in your code where you want it.", there's a catch: my application has severe performance issues, and I like to avoid too many calls to `OutputDebugString()`.

Does anybody have an idea? I've already tried the method I've found in [this URL](http://www.howzatt.demon.co.uk/articles/SimpleDebugger.html) but this seems not to be working due to missing DLLs. In top of this, I don't like the solution that much, because it contains a `while` loop: I'm looking for some kind of subscription where I can subscribe to and be warned when the message arrives.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: To check whether a debugger is attached, periodically poll the value of [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345). This is a light call; it's just returning the value of the `BeingDebugged` field in the PEB.

Comment: There is no such message or event. You're thinking of the events that a debugger gets, such as in the article and code you linked to. The process getting debugged just has to poll this value, or always check it to gate calling `OutputDebugString`. If you're overly concerned about efficiency, you could save a function call by checking the value directly. Include winternl.h and check `NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->BeingDebugged`. This is implemented as an inline intrinsic.